# Recover data from disabled iPhone with known passcode

Tags: iphone, recovery, flash-memory, ntp

my friend broke his iPhone 4S digitizer in very unhappy way. He didn't have **backup** or **synced computers** and he had **cellular data turn off**.

I successfully replaced digitizer and turn on the iPhone. Whow! ***Your iPhone is disabled for 47 years***. Okay, so normally after battery replacement iPhone time is flushed and after reboot new time is fetched over NTP via cellular data, synced PC or already signed Wi-Fi. Not working in this case..

So theoretically there are two possible solutions:

1. Somehow fetch or rewrite correct clock's value
2. Mount NAND flash drive, export keys from CPU, merge it with
   passcode, decrypt data

Any advice or experiences?

Thanks!